# Yii 2 Multiple Users in Basic Template

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I was searching for answers but all I see are RBAC implementations and they're on advanced template. Saw this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user/ but it's in advanced template as well.

RBAC is way too complicated for me and I am still starting to learn more about Yii 2 with the basic template.

Anyone can help me implement a multiple users in Yii 2 basic template without using RBAC? It will be much of a help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be of the same concept in Yii 1.1.x, where you initialize two components of the CWebUser, but this time in Yii2, the user model (which implements Identity) is the one we will be initializing twice on the configuration:

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
   'admin' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\Admin',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
],
```

(or if you don't have a separate `Admin` database table, also use `common\models\User` for the `admin` component `identityClass`. In any way, it will be instantiated as a separate object and will have separate contents and states)

This way, you can:

```
Yii::$app->user->function()
```

and

```
Yii::$app->admin->function()
```

Comment: If you add extra components, you need to set that class

'admin' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\Admin',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true, 
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
],

Answer (score 0):

You want to switch between two model `identityClass` for login,

Just include this in your admin Login Controller to change `identityClass`.

```
Yii::$app->user->identityClass = 'app\models\Admin';
```

And in the user component of config/web.php.

```
'identityClass' = 'app\models\Admin';
```